# Call a method of view controller from a thread

Tags: ios

I have a View Controller where the GUI logic lies

and I have a thread which is started from this view controller and there I am doing some processing

I have two views which i want to flip after some time from my thread

As I know we can do the flipping from view controllers only

So please suggest me a way to call method of view controller from my custom thread class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have tried so far please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first options that comes trough my mind are:

If you have access to the view controller from your thread class
    then you could do:

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [yourVc callMethodToFlip];  
  });
```

If you don't have access you can use notifications:

**YourVC.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(methodForFlip)  name:A_NOTIFICATION_NAME object:nil];
}
```

**InYourTreadClass.m**

```
-(void)someMethodThatExecutesAsync {
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:A_NOTIFICATION_NAME
       object:nil]; //or yoou can send an object
});
}
```

The other method would be, create a method for your custom thread class that takes a block parameter, whenever you create a  thread from your vc send the block parameter which will be called from your thread also using `dispatch_async`

Comment: This I think would be suitable for me. Will try it for sure. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) to perform your asynchronous operations. That way you can perform intensive operations off of the main thread, and then come back to the main thread to perform your animations with this simple syntax:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, kNilOptions), ^{
        //Calculations
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Do animations
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your thread class, add a pointer to your view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) YourViewController *viewController;
```

When your view controller creates the thread, set the thread's `viewController` property to your view controller:

```
yourThreadClass.viewController = self;
```

In your View Controller class, create a `flipViews` method:

```
-(void)flipViews
{
    // ...
}
```

In your thread class, whenever it needs to flip the views, just call:

```
[viewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector:(flipViews) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: I can not add pointer of view controller in my thread because I am already have a pointer of the Thread class in View Controller... So cross referencing will not be allowed...